# Can the extracted features from the factor analysis be used in data reduction using SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am doing a project for data reduction using a term-document matrix Amn where m is the number of variables and n is the number of cases. Using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), $$A=USV`$$ where S is the diagonal matrix of singular values. If I reduce the original matrix A into Ar, where r is the rank of the matrix in a reduced form, then $$A_r=U_r S_r V`_r$$ Now I am wondering if r is the same number of extracted features, or factors, which could be obtained from the factor analysis using SPSS program for example. I mean can I use r=k where k is the number of factors obtained from FA that explain most of the variance among the variables to get $$A_r$$.

Answer (score 1):

No. SVD and FA are not equivalent. [Truncated SVD (or PCA)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca) minimizes the Frobenius norm (see Eckart-Young theorem) of the matrix, while FA assumes an independent additive Gaussian noise per variable. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysis

Comment: So in doing SVD, how many factors should I use and on what base should I choose them?

Comment: That depends on your assumptions and your analysis.

Comment: In factor analysis, things are clear as the number of extracted factors are those that explain most the variance among the variables with good analysis if more than 70% of the total variance, but in SVD what is the criteria for choosing them? What do you mean by my assumption and analysis?

Comment: Same can be done. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation